# Primitive recursion with varying parameters

Tags: computability

Suppose $g\colon \mathbb{N}^k \to \mathbb{N}$, $v_1,\ldots,v_r\colon \mathbb{N}^k \to \mathbb{N}^k$ and $h\colon \mathbb{N}^{k+r+1} \to \mathbb{N}$ are all primitive recursive, and define $f\colon \mathbb{N}^{k+1} \to \mathbb{N}$ by
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(0,\underline{x}) &= g(\underline{x}) \cr
f(n+1,\underline{x}) &= h(n, \underline{x}, f(n,v_1(\underline{x})),\ldots, f(n,v_r(\underline{x})))
\end{aligned}
$$
(note that for $r=1$ and $v_1$ the identity function, this is precisely a definition by primitive recursion).

If I am not mistaken, $f$ is then primitive recursive as well¹.

**Questions:**

- Does this form of recursion have a name²?  (Or if not exactly this, then a more general form which includes the one above and which is satisfied by p.r. functions.)
- Is there some standard reference for this fact?
- Is there a proof that isn't horribly tedious (contra the one sketched in footnote 1 below), based on the standard textbook definition of p.r. functions (e.g., as [found in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function))?

1. Sketch of proof: from $n$ and $x$ we can primitive recursively construct some encoding of the full $r$-ary tree of depth $n$ of values $v_{i_1}(v_{i_2}(\cdots(v_{i_s}(\underline{x}))\cdots))$, since this is requires at most exponentially many computations, and then evaluate $f(i,\underline{y})$ on each node $\underline{y}$ at depth $n-i$ in this tree.
2. Note: I thought it was “course-of-values” recursion, but “course-of-values” actually refers to the so-to-speak dual case when $f(n,\underline{x})$ refers to $f(i,\underline{x})$ for several different $i<n$ but for the same $\underline{x}$ rather than, as is the case here, $f(n-1,\underline{v})$ for several different $\underline{v}$.

**Edit+comment:** answering a comment by Saroupille, the $v_i$ take values in $\mathbb{N}^k$ (rather than, as I had initially written, in $\mathbb{N}$).  Maybe I should also have allowed $v_i$ bo take $n$ as input in the second formula, but I guess that would be easy to fix anyway.  Probably more subtle, and maybe also desirable, is the case where we allow $v_i$ to take expressions in $f(n,\ldots)$ as input — but let me refrain from editing the question any further.

Comment: Is your formula well-typed? Since $f(n,v_1(x))$ is not a natural number but a partial application (except if $k=1$, but I guess this is not the intent).

Comment: @Saroupille Fixed (I want $v_i$ to take values in $\mathbb{N}^k$).

Comment: You could underline each $v_i$ to emphasise that it is a tuple of functions.

Comment: Using a pairing function, you can just assume $k=1$ without loss of generality.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Agreed, $k$ is very much a red herring here. On the other hand, $r$ is not.

Comment: Is there a reason you do not allow $n$ to occur as an argument of each $v_i$?

Comment: @AnupamDas No, this was merely an oversight. I just happened not to need them in the case where this came up, but I have no good reason not to have an $n$ here.

Answer (score 4):

I would call the scheme you have written **unnested type-1 primitive recursion**.

First, type-1 primitive recursion allows us to abstract number arguments to define a type-1 function by induction on the (0,succ)-representation of numbers. Referring to your example above we may define $f(n): \mathbb N^k \to \mathbb N$ (think of this as $\lambda \underline x . f(n,\underline x)$) by:

- $f(0) = g$
- $f(n+1) = \lambda \underline x . h(n,\underline x, f(n)(\underline{v}_1(\underline x)),\dots,f(n)(\underline {v}_r(\underline x))$.

Higher-type primitive recursion is standard terminology in higher-order computability and proof theory (see e.g. [Avigad-Feferman chapter on Dialectica](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/avigad/Papers/dialect.pdf)). A priori, type-1 primitive recursion is strictly more powerful than usual (type-0) primitive recursion, as it allows for the definition of the [Ackermann-Péter function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function). However in your scheme, you have no applications of the recursive call to terms including itself. In spirit this is what underlies Kleene's *predicative* higher primitive recursion (outlined in Section 5.1 of [Avigad-Feferman](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/avigad/Papers/dialect.pdf)), however you are also allowing multiple instances of the recursive call with *compositions during recursion* (terminology e.g. from Section 3.4.3 [Bellantoni's thesis](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=fca3985d1321ab7bb851fdae658a92508feaa500)). I have seen this called **unnested recursion** (as opposed to nested recursion such as the definition of Ackermann-Péter function). I am not sure how standard this is but, for instance, I have used the terminology in my own papers (e.g. Section 4 of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.01114)), and it has seemed non-controversial when communicating about the scheme. With this terminology, by the way, there is no reason not to allow $n$ as a further argument to each $v_i$.

I do not know a proof that primitive recursive functions (PRF) are closed under your scheme other than the one you describe, which seems standard. Note that some simplification could be made by simply prescribing a monotone bounding function (mbf) that is in PRF, as PRF is closed under bounded search. E.g., now assuming $k=1$ for simplicity as Emil suggests, if $b_g,b_h,b_{v_i}$ are mbfs for $g,h,v_i$ respectively, then $b_v = \max (b_{v_1}, \dots, b_{v_r})$ is a mbf for all $v_i$. Now the function you defined is bounded by the mbf $b_f$ given by:

- $b_f(0 , \underline x) = b_g (\underline x)$
- $b_f(n+1,\underline x) = b_h (n,\underline x , b_f (n, b_v (\underline x)), \dots, b_f (n,b_v (\underline x)))$

This is an instance of primitive recursion with (single) composition during recursion (cf. [Bellantoni](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=fca3985d1321ab7bb851fdae658a92508feaa500)). Closure of PRF under this scheme is well-known. E.g. a similar argument is used for Lemma 2.4.4 of [Avigad-Feferman](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/avigad/Papers/dialect.pdf), where the function $e$ carries out the sort of 'pre-computation' you describe in your proof sketch.